# How to search dynamicaly a value into my APEX database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am working into an Apex app and I am fancing a problem. I have created a form to add orders. The user needs to select a product and how many of the product he/she wants. Then, I will calculate the total $ and add that information (all of it) to my Orders Database. However, I don´t know how to get the product price from my database (entry product_price) dynamicaly. I need to wait until the user select the product and then do the search

I have read that the best option is to use dynamic actions. I have tried creating one with the following SQL/PL statement, but it doesn´t work:

```
RETURN (
  SELECT PRODUCTS.PRICE
  FROM PRODUCTS
  WHERE PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID=(RETURN :P12_PRODUCT;));
```

As you can see, what I want with this code is to select the price from my products database using product_id as filter. P12_Product is the ID of the product selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select your Product LOV item, e.g. `P12_PRODUCT`
- Create Dynamic Action

  - name: "onChange - get product price"
  - event: "change"

    - Action: "Set Value"
    - Set Type: "SQL Statement"
    - SQL Statement: `SELECT PRODUCTS.PRICE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID = :P12_PRODUCT`
    - Items to Submit: `P12_PRODUCT`
    - Affected Item(s): Select the item you want the product price to return into, e.g. `P12_PRODUCT_PRICE`